# Function Not Working Properly

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x, ctypes

NOTE: I have a whole bunch of code, so it is currently stored [here](https://gist.github.com/Axmill/394a4f577b0ee98465a5).

So, I have those two files. The CPP file is part of a C .so library which uses ctypes to integrate with Python. However, when I run test.py, it does not print anything, even though I assigned the return type of

```
interfaceLib.concatString()
```

to the variable "text", which is then printed.

Answer (score 0):

Function calls in ctypes return an int by default. You will need to specify the restype of your library function. Try the following:

```
from ctypes import CDLL, c_char_p

interfaceLib = CDLL('Shared_Lib/bin/Library/libShared_Lib.so')

interfaceLib.test()
str1 = "H"
str2 = "I"
interfaceLib.concatString.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]
interfaceLib.concatString.restype = c_char_p
text = interfaceLib.concatString(str1.encode('utf-8'), str2.encode('utf-8'))
print(text)
```

Comment: Now I get the error   File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    text = interfaceLib.concatString(str1, str2) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Comment: Try removing the line `interfaceLib.concatString.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]`, or converting the strings to byte arrays with `encode` (see the edited answer). Setting `argtypes` is not necessary for integers, strings or byte arrays, but for all other types it is.

Comment: The C interface can't use C++ `string` objects. Change it to `char *`.